# Embedding Workbench JBPM v6.2 In Application

Tags: jbpm, embedding, workbench

I want to display some jbpm perspective in my web application, i do like this example, i'm using jbpm v6.2:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>Editor frame below:</p>
    <iframe height='800' src='http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console?standalone=true&perspective=Process Instances' width='1000'></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have an error : "Refused to display `'http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/kie-wb.html?perspective=StandaloneEditorPerspective&standalone=true&header=SAMEORIGIN'` in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."

Please help me fix this error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @vu Anh, According to my Knowledge , its showing in the running process list only, But i need for list of task for assigning to me , and one more thing Right now i am using JBPM Version 7.1.0 latest , The iframe link not working for me, could you provide  me a correct link for archive the list of task list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your web.xml inside the war, you can configure it there:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/kie-wb-distributions/blob/6.2.0.Final/kie-wb/kie-wb-distribution-wars/src/main/assembly/wildfly8/WEB-INF/web.xml#L30

You should specify which page can embed the workbench, in the form
ALLOW-FROM uri

Comment: Thank you for your support , i am appreciate on you, for the CORS solution, i need to know how to embedded list of task assign for me in JBPM version 7.1.0 , if you know please let me know ,Thank you..

Comment: I configure SSO between jbpm v6.2.0 final an CAS. It work. If u want to embedded list of task assign for user, i can use iframe.

Comment: p/s: You can use iframe with value of perspective=Task list